# How to dynamically attach files into an email using gmailr?

Tags: r, email

I've gone through a couple of links related to this question, one of them is the link below:
https://github.com/jennybc/send-email-with-r

This link was very helpful in creating mimes, setting up the mails and sending em across.
However, I'm looking for something more, so I'm posting this question.

I have a folder with a logo (PNG) file and some JPEG files. I also have an MS excel list of names, e-mail addresses and a field called receipt numbers. The JPEG files are named according to the receipt numbers.
How can I use the 'gmailr' package to include the logo along with some text in the e-mail body? Also, I would like to match the JPEG images with each receipt number and attach the file in respective mails.

I'm new to Stack Overflow, hence please excuse any mistake from my end in the question. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this in R, but if you are using Excel, and it sounds like you are, you can do all of that in Excel.  Just follow the instructions below.

Example

```
Make a list in Sheets("Sheet1") with :

In column A : Names of the people
In column B : E-mail addresses
In column C:Z : Filenames like this C:\Data\Book2.xls (don't have to be Excel files)
```

The Macro will loop through each row in "Sheet1" and if there is a E-mail address in column B
and file name(s) in column C:Z it will create a mail with this information and send it.

```
Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
        Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Testfile"
                .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

                .Send  'Or use .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```